# how could I append different values into an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, push

I'm trying to append city names by clicking in the < li> elements and adding them up to the array but I'm stuck, this is what I've got so far:

```
<div id='cities'>pick cities: 
   <div id='csffs'></div>
   <ul>
       <li>San francisco</li>
       <li>Palo Alto</li>
       <li>San Diego</li>
       <li>Los Angeles</li>
       <li>Toledo</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$('li').on('mouseup', function() {
        var city = $(this).text();
        var bunch_of_cities = ['New York','Cleveland','Port Clinton','Toledo'];
    if($.inArray(city,bunch_of_cities) > -1){
    //if found, not added up to the array
        city = null;
    }else{
    // if not found, then add it up to the array
        bunch_of_cities.push(city);
    }
        $("#csffs").html(free_to.join());


});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_39_34/y825ttL5/1/)

The problem I'm facing is that I need to be able to add more than 1 city and not as it happens with the demo I left above:

i.e:

```
New York,Cleveland,Port Clinton,Toledo [Whichever city was clicked]
```

I want something like this:

```
New York,Cleveland,Port Clinton,Toledo,San francisco, Palo Alto,....so forth and so on
```

Feel free to change bits or give me a better way to do this and of course Thanks for your time!!!

PD: I've been learning to code by my own so forgive the sloppy code of above

Comment: Declare the `bunch..` array in global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your `var bunch_of_cities` in your mouseup function so it is recreated every time the function is called. You have to declare it out of scope that function. For example

```
var bunch_of_cities = ['New York','Cleveland','Port Clinton','Toledo'];

$('li').on('mouseup', function() {
        var city = $(this).text();
    if($.inArray(city,bunch_of_cities) > -1){
    //if found, not added up to the array
        city = null;
    }else{
    // if not found, then add it up to the array
        bunch_of_cities.push(city);
    }
        $("#csffs").html(free_to.join());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the initial array `bunch_of_cities` in global scope. The reason being, everytime you modify this array it will be available as the same for all functions.

Your code used to initialize the array on every click event.

```
var bunch_of_cities = ['New York', 'Cleveland', 'Port Clinton', 'Toledo'];
$('li').on('mouseup', function () {
     var city = $(this).text();

     if ($.inArray(city, bunch_of_cities) > -1) {
         //if found not added up to the array
         city = null;
     } else {
         // if not found, then add it up to the array
         bunch_of_cities.push(city);
     }
     $("#ok").html(bunch_of_cities.join());
});
```

Also, I dont think you need the `if(...)`, use this

```
if ($.inArray(city, bunch_of_cities) == -1) {
     // if not found, then add it up to the array
     bunch_of_cities.push(city);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y825ttL5/4/)** <sub>(based on your fiddle)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I changed a bit of it.
The array in which you are trying to append data should be global.

Have a look:

```
var bunch_of_cities = ['New York', 'Cleveland', 'Port Clinton', 'Toledo'];
$('li').on('mouseup', function() {
  var city = $(this).text();
  if ($.inArray(city, bunch_of_cities) > -1) {
    //if found not added up to the array
    city = null;
  } else {
    // if not found, then add it up to the array
    bunch_of_cities.push(city);
  }
  $("#ok").html(bunch_of_cities.join());
});
```